# How to configure logs to be only in JSON format in spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, logback

In my spring boot app the following configuration is used for adding JSON logs via `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>time</timestamp>
                <message>msg</message>
                <thread>thread</thread>
                <logger>logger</logger>
                <version>[ignore]</version>
                <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="all">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

However, when running the app both versions of logs (non-JSON & JSON) are traced:

```
2017-08-08 07:31:49.718  INFO 6849 --- [           main] .s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer : Jetty started on port(s) 10000 (http/1.1)
{"time":"2017-08-08T07:31:49.718+02:00","msg":"Jetty started on port(s) 10000 (http/1.1)","logger":"org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer","thread":"main","level":"INFO","HOSTNAME":"ilya-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-4th","caller_class_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer","caller_method_name":"start","caller_file_name":"JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java","caller_line_number":144}
```

Is is possible to configure logback / logstash encoder, so that only JSON version would be available in the logs and non-JSON would be skipped ?

Comment: How to DISABLING json in log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh, stupid me - one should just remove the line from logback config which adds base logging:

`<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>`